# Setting variables for async org export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, variables

I have this function:

```
(defun cpm/org-export--file-beamer-handout ()
  "Export file content to PDF handout. Handout uses a distinctive quote style."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-latex-default-quote-environment "quote-b")
        (org-export-exclude-tags '("slides" "noexport")))
    (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil nil nil nil '(:latex-class "beamer-handout"))))
```

Which works fine if I am exporting synchronously. But the let binding fails to work if exporting asynchronously. I'm clearly missing something about binding variables with `let`. Is there a way to make this work asynchronously?

Comment: Async happens in an external process: I think you'll need to arrange it so that when the process gets initialized, it reads the settings from a file. See  `org-export-async-start` and `org-export-async-init-file` for some info. Looks like a fair amount of black magic to me (IOW, I could be very wrong and YMMV). Good luck!

Comment: See also the manual: `C-h i g(org)The Export Dispatcher` and scroll down to the `C-a` description.